# Is there any documentation for the "Dojo constraint language" or "constraint object"?

Tags: dojo, dojo-1.9

In the documentation for the [Dojo NumberTextBox](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/NumberTextBox.html), the wording makes reference to the "Dojo Constraint language" and even includes a helpful [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/numbersDates.html#quickstart-numbersdates).   Unfortunately the link goes to a page which says only `this document has been deprecated.`  Not very helpful.

This "constraint language" or "constraint object" is used extensively in Dojo but doesn't seem to be documented **anywhere** in any comprehensive form.

Does anybody know if such documentation exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to know what's available in the Dojo constraints is by using the [API documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/). If you look at the API documentation of the [`dijit/form/NumberTextBox`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/form/NumberTextBox), you will notice that in the tree on the left side you can click it open and see an object called [`__Constraints`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/form/NumberTextBox.__Constraints).

Another thing you could do with deprecated docs is change the version of it in the URL, so for your page it would become: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/numbersDates.html#quickstart-numbersdates.

Comment: The API documentation hint was perfect!   Have I mentioned how much I hate the way Dojo does their API doc interface?   It's bad web design laid out like a buffet.  (IMHO.)   Thanks for pointing that out to me.